# Error: Executing consumer group command failed due to Request GROUP_COORDINATOR failed on brokers List(localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null))

Tags: apache-kafka

I am using single node Kafka cluster(version 0.10.2) and single node zookeeper (3.4.9). I am having approx 310 topics with Avg 100 partitions per topic. On Kafka broker when I am running the command to check consumer status in a group

> ./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
>   --describe --group

Most of the time it is throwing an error:

```
Error: Executing consumer group command failed due to Request GROUP_COORDINATOR failed on brokers List(localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null))
```

and rest of the time it is showing the correct result.

I googled it but was not able to find the exact result of this error.Can someone tell me how to fix this error? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I  encounter this issue also. Actually,
./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --list
works well, and I get the groups list. 
but this one doesn't work. weird.

Comment: @Spybdai I increased the the kafka process memory and its working fine for me now.

Comment: @Abhimanyu Did process memory increase fixed the problem permanently?

Comment: @AnkitBatra Actually I reduced and optimised the way kafka producers were producing message . and it solved my issue .

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you can connect to localhost:9092?

I get this error whenever the url to the bootstrap server is wrong.

Try whatever other host and you will see the same error.

Comment: @Rento How is this possible that some times its working and some times its failing . and I have tried with the the server ip also in place of localhost it still fails

Comment: Ok, I misread your post. Indeed, I can't explain why it's intermittently failing.